# How do I use NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper in my tests and have more than one test pass?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

Here's my NUnit test code (simplified to isolate the issue):

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/route")]
    public string Route1()
    {
        return "route";
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MyTestFixture
{
    private NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper _bootstrapper;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8767");
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        this._bootstrapper = new NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper(() => kernel, config);
        this._bootstrapper.Start();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        if (this._bootstrapper != null)
        {
            this._bootstrapper.Dispose();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyTest1()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:8767/api/route");
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            Assert.That(content, Is.EqualTo("\"route\""));
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyTest2()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:8767/api/route");
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            Assert.That(content, Is.EqualTo("\"route\""));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run that using the default `NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper` the first test passes fine, but the second throws an exception, saying:

> A registration already exists for URI 'http://localhost:8767/'.

When I examine the code for these two files:

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.WebApi.Selfhost/NinjectWebApiSelfHost.cs

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web.Common.SelfHost/NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper.cs

I can see why - an `HttpSelfHostServer` is created in the latter and `OpenAsync()` is called on the server, but `CloseAsync()` isn't called on the server - **is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?  How do I get `NinjectSelfHostBootstrapper` to work with subsequently called tests?**

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @RobertKaucher No, sorry.